# Finding Active Visual Studio 2008 Connection Strings

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config, database-connection

Is there a simple way to figure out which connection strings are being used in my web.config.  After a lot of LinqToSQL testing, I have a few extra connection strings sitting in my web.config that I'm sure aren't being used, but I'm not exactly sure which ones are/aren't.  Any quick ways to single these out.  The obvious solution is to pull them one by one and do a comprehensive debug of the whole app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered this one.  You could also do a Find in all files, or if it's strongly typed find all references and then remove them.  Ultimately I'd rely on tests, even if they were just some comprehensive smoke tests.